# wcf service and windows phone device

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8, iis-express

i'm developing a Windows phone 8 application which consume my wcf service. 
Can i host my service locally on my laptop ( using iis express ) and use my phone consume the service? 
I can connect to service from wp8 emulator, but it doesn't work when i deploy and test on my phone.

Comment: Can you please specify the detailed error. So we can look into that for rectification.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a result from your consumed service on the emulator having a direct access to your localhost ip (127.0.0.1), but when you move the software to run on the device, it doesn't find the service in that IP anymore.

This page has a lot of information on the configuration of this matter and probably what you're looking for:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj684580%28v=vs.105%29.aspx